# JavaFX TitledPane: Remove Title

Tags: java, javafx

is it possible to completely remove the title of a TitledPane?

I managed to make it invisible using the following code in the css-file:

```
.titled-pane > .title{
    -fx-background-color: rgba(0, 100, 0, 0.0);
    -fx-font-size: 0;
}
```

But it still takes up space, and when I hover over it with my mouse, the cursor changes. Changing the padding didn't help either.

Basically, I only need the expandable / collapsable abilities of the TitledPane, which are executed when a Button is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [TitledPane's Substructure](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#titledpane), the `title` is a `HBox`. So we can lookup it and hide then:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Pane title = (Pane) titledPane.lookup(".title");
        if (title != null) {
            title.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
});
```

It should be run in `Platform.runLater(...)` after the scene constructed and rendered.

Comment: Worked for me, too, thanks. I was looking to get at the height property of that header section to fit a button to it, and this was just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

A bit old, but you could do this by CSS as well. 
Given your titledPane has id filterTitledPane, you could have :

```
#filterTitledPane .title {
    -fx-pref-height: 1;
}

#filterTitledPane .title .text {
    visibility: false;
}
```